# Calculate new value using mutate and formula in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

How would one calculate a new value in the dplyr pipe using mutate and e.g. stat_poly_eq?

The following code produces a plot with a formula for the lm within each facet. Is it possible to calculate a new y using the formula in the `stat_poly_eq` before the plotting?

```
data %>%
  group_by(year, type, class) %>%
  filter(avv_yday > 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=weight, x=age)) +
  facet_grid(year ~ type + class) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black") +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~")), 
               parse = TRUE) +         
  geom_point() +
  ylim(100, 500)
```